# can't use scss loader to config webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

I've just started using Webpack and it's quite complicated for me.
After many hours I understood that it just supports JS/JSON to build but we can handle other types with `loader`. So far I have succeeded to load .css files with the below config

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                include: /\.module\.css$/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
                exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
            },
        ]
    }
```

but now I want to make another config to load SCSS but I'm failed with every try.
please guide me.

I also tried to install many packages to load scss such as

```
npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev
```

and after that, I changed webpackconfig to :

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

but it still can't build it and give me the following command:
*You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file*

Comment: I fixed it by using : `npm install style-loader css-loader sass-loader` in my terminal